# ASP.NET MVC - Can i have multiple names for the same action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

ASP.NET MVC - Can i have multiple names for the same action?

In the same controller... Can i have multiple names for the same action?

I am looking for a complete multiple language solution. Essentially the i want all the logic to be sa same but change the "keywords" (actions, controllers in the url) depending on language.

Comment: Couldn't you set 
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture instead?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't have multiple names for same action. It will be different actions. This is the way how mvc works. Mabe it's better to implement described behaviour with routing.

```
routes.MapRoute("Lang1RouteToController1Action1",
 "Lang1Controller/Lang1Action/{id}",
 new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute("Lang2RouteToController1Action1",
 "Lang2Controller/Lang2Action/{id}",
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Ofcourse you'll have to create many routes, but you can make config file or store routing data in database, and just create them in loop on application start. Anyway I think it's better then creating planty of methods, becouse if you'll want to add one more language you'll need to find actions all over your controllers and recompile code. But in case of routes and config file - it become not so hard.
Second thing is  Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home") extension - you'll have to implement your own to return localized action link.

Comment: Had this idea too, after i posted. Do you think i can have different action names call the same class to do something and have these classes (action logic) in a different file?

Comment: Yes, you can. But as I've already said, this will couse a lot of pain when you'll deside to add new language. Furthermore it will look strange to see in code methods wich named in different languages and do the same thing. I realy think that routing will be much more appropriate in your case, becouse it uses strings. And every tyme we localize something - we localize strings - not names of the methods. But it's only my opinion :)

Answer (score 8):

I know I'm late to the party but in in case someone is googling, I created an attribute (inspired from ActionName attribute) that matches multiple names as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web.Mvc;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class ActionNamesAttribute : ActionNameSelectorAttribute
{
    public ActionNamesAttribute(params string[] names)
    {
        if (names == null) {
            throw new ArgumentException("ActionNames cannot be empty or null", "names");
        }
        this.Names = new List<string>();
        foreach (string name in names)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            {
                this.Names.Add(name);
            }
        }
    }

    private List<string> Names { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValidName(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        return this.Names.Any(x => String.Equals(actionName, x, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }
}
```

To use:

```
[ActionNames("CreateQuickItem", "CreateFullItem")]
public ActionResult Create() {}
```

Comment: any suggestion for net core?

Comment: Fraid I'm still stuck in .net land, only a newbie in core. Hopefully someone else can add something.

Comment: no worries i found the alternate @Mark Ball

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if having multiple action names is possible. One way I could think of doing this is by defining multiple actions with different names that internal cal/execute the same action.

Comment: Nice workaround! But the "final" url that is produced will have the name of the "main" action that every other action calls.

Comment: I don't think so. I am not suggesting redirection to another action. You can simply execute another action (that is another public method in the controller class) and return it's result to the browser while executing an action.

Comment: Ok... Now i get it. I just "wrap" the "another language" action around a generic action, both "doing" the same thing
This seems logical :)