# ASP.NET MVC - Duplicate ActionName attribute on 1 ActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET MVC - Can i have multiple names for the same action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710454/asp-net-mvc-can-i-have-multiple-names-for-the-same-action)

I was wondering if its possible to have two actions point to the same ActionResult in a controller, like so:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("ManualSearch")]
[ActionName("AddProduct")]
public virtual ActionResult MyPostAction(MyModel model) 
{

// do code...

}
```

The reason for doing this is because I have 2 views that each process an action differently but they both contain a form, which essentially is doing the same thing, so I was wondering to just make those 2 forms POST to the same action, like I tried above, only apparently its not possible to duplicate the ActionName attribute.

Comment: Short answer: No, you can't. You can though modify your routing so that different URLs will point to the same action.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not to create two different actions and a private method called by the two?

```
public ActionResult Action1(MyModel model)
{
     return PrivateAction(model);
}

public ActionResult Action2(MyModel model)
{
     return PrivateAction(model);
}

private ActionResult PrivateAction(MyModel model)
{
      .... do stuff....
}
```

I think easiest things are the most reliable ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answers, i've just duplicated the original action for the 2nd action for the time being, will change it to your answer

Comment: You can also add [NonAction] attribute for PrivateAction if it's public